# how to change an operand of a load instruction?

Tags: llvm

For example:

```
%3 = load float, float* addrspacecast (float addrspace(3)* @_ZZ16imGlobalFunctionvE1a to float*), align 4
```

Here, what I want to do is to change

```
float* addrspacecast (float addrspace(3)* @_ZZ16imGlobalFunctionvE1a to float*)
```

into

`float addrspace(3)* @_ZZ16imGlobalFunctionvE1a`

But, `float* addrspacecast (float addrspace(3)* @_ZZ16imGlobalFunctionvE1a to float*)` is *ConstantExpr* which cannot extracts its operand such as `float addrspace(3)* @_ZZ16imGlobalFunctionvE1a`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)